# PHP to log counter with date in the format

Tags: php

I have a php counter code that logs the counts starting with 1 and so on.

I want to make the format of the counts as: YYYYMM-1 i.e., 201805-1, 201805-2 and so on. In which the first four digits are current year, the next two are current month and the next digit after hyphen is the log counts.

The code I have is:

```
$file = 'counter.txt';

$counter = 1;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    $counter += file_get_contents($file);
}
file_put_contents($file, $counter);
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
$file = 'counter.txt';

$date = date('mY-');
$counter = intval($date) + 1;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    $counter += file_get_contents($file);
}
file_put_contents($file, $counter);
```

For which I get a result in my counter.txt as "156058" etc.

Please help me in getting it to work just as my desired format. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current script is casting the date to an integer and then adding an integer to it.

What you want is to keep it a string and concatenate the counter to it when you write the file. Then explode / split on '-' when you read the file:

```
<?php

   $file = "OUT";

   $date = date('mY-');
   $counter = 1;

   if (file_exists($file)) {
      $data = file_get_contents($file);
      $parts = explode('-', $data);
      $counter = $parts[1] + 1;
   }

   file_put_contents($file, $date . $counter);
```